# How to verify whether content is shared on Facebook or not?

Tags: facebook, sharing

I was given a requirement where the user of a site shares content on Facebook and gets a coupon in return. This doesn't seem technically possible at the moment as content is shared through the share button. Is there a way I could detect if some content has been shared on Facebook or at least whether someone has clicked on it?

The user will design the interior of room and the designed image will be shared on Facebook and in return he'll get the coupon code sent to his email.

Is it possible?

Comment: Please check: [Is there a way to programmatically check if a user shared a link on Facebook?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5363517/is-there-a-way-to-programmatically-check-if-a-user-shared-a-link-on-facebook)

Comment: Facebook returns the total amount of shares of a website or URL. You can manage to generate an unique URL for each user, and then check if the count > 0 to verify the share

Answer (score 11, accepted):

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/reference/share-dialog

This one will only return an object id if the user is authorized with publish_actions, else you don´t know if something is shared. The Share Button plugin can´t be used for that either.

The major problem is that **it is not allowed** though. You can´t incentivize likes and shares - meaning, **you are not allowed to reward a user with a coupon for sharing something**. You may want to check out the platform policy: https://developers.facebook.com/policy/

Remember, users need to like something because they really "like" it, and share something because they really WANT to share it.

Comment: Also please see this link https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/examples-platform-policy-4.4